Craft4 Multisite to use a selected site to copy instead of main site
My website is on craft v4.10.8
My craft site has multiple languages using multisite feature.
When I normally create a new multisite the queue worker creates a job that copies the main site (English site for me) to this new language site.
I want to launch additional language sites that are related.
Let me explain.
I already have my-domain.com/es
I want to add my-domain.com/es-la
Instead of this new site copying over the english site i want it to copy the /es site.
Currently my craft version does not support this.
Can anyone help me find a solution to resolve this?
From what I have read I see that there is a hook called onAfterSaveSite
My current plan is to create a craft extension plugin to alter the site used on this hook so that when i push the code update for new language my production site uses the selected language to do the initial copy.
Is this the correct method?
Is there a preexisting solution?
I have looked into site copy plugin. it does not do what i need in a effective manner.
